# update all line of table in erlang

Tags: erlang

I have this table :

```
-record(person, {id, firstname, lastname, address}).
```

for example this table contains this values :

```
2  alen     dumas      paris
5  franco   mocci      parma
3  ali      othmani    london
```

Now I have the variable  `Key`  which  contains this value  `10`

I want to develop a function in erlang which will modify  all `id` of the table `person`

the new value of this `id`  will be the previous value + the value of `Key`

mean the table person will became like this

```
   12  alen     dumas      paris
    15  franco   mocci      parma
    13  ali      othmani    london
```

meaning each `id` will be added by 10 (is the value of `Key`)   :(2+10)    (5+10)   (3+10)

I try with your code :

```
testmodify()->
    Key=22, 
    [ P#person{id=P#person.id+Key} || P <- Persons ].
```

but I have this error in the sysntax : `variable Persons is unbound`

I try to resolve this problem with this code :

```
testmodify()->
    Key=22, 
    [ P#person{id=P#person.id+Key} || P <- mnesia:table(person) ].
```

but I have this error :

```
1> model:testmodify().
** exception error: no function clause matching 
                    model:'-testmodify/0-lc$^0/1-0-'({qlc_handle,
                                                      {qlc_table,
                                                       #Fun<mnesia.20.112329951>,
                                                       true,
                                                       #Fun<mnesia.21.62211129>, 
                                                       #Fun<mnesia.22.75429001>, 
                                                       #Fun<mnesia.23.26336897>, 
                                                       #Fun<mnesia.26.62819299>, 
                                                       #Fun<mnesia.25.51075493>, 
                                                       #Fun<mnesia.24.47804912>, 
                                                       '=:=',undefined,
                                                       no_match_spec}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table is stored as a list:

```
[ P#person{id=P#person.id+Key} || P <- Persons ].
```

**UPDATE:** For an Mnesia table, you can retrieve similar results with QLC:

```
-include_lib("stdlib/include/qlc.hrl").
⋮
[ P#person{id=P#person.id+Key} || P <- mnesia:table(person) ].
```

Note that this only gives you a list of transformed person records. To update the records, you'll probably have to remove the existing records and write the new records in a transaction, since a record with a modified key (assuming that's what `id` is) is treated as a different record — something like this:

```
mnesia:transaction(fun() ->
    Old = [ P                            || P <- mnesia:table(person) ],
    New = [ P#person{id=P#person.id+Key} || P <- Old ],
    [ mnesia:delete({person, P#Person.id}) || P <- Old ],
    [ mnesia:write(P) || P <- New ]
end)
```

You might be able to do this in a single pass with `mnesia:foldr`, but I don't know what happens if you issue `mnesia:delete` and `mnesia:write` inside `mnesia:foldr`. You might get stuck in an infinite loop (but don't quote me on that).

Comment: I think in order to update all ligne of the table person we should work in loop

Comment: @aliothmani: I didn't know you meant an Mnesia table. The above solution applies to a `Person` variable holding a list of `person` records.